# No display scaling option in System Settings for external display in macOS Ventura

Tags: display, displayport, resolution

I have an Iiyama PL2779Q monitor that I’ve been using for years without a problem. I connect my Macbook Pro to it through the displayport. The resolution is 1920 x 1080, which is fine. However, since yesterday the scaling option disappeared in the system settings. Now everything looks really big. Is there a way to get the scaling back?

[image: No display scaling option in System Settings for external display in macOS Ventura]

Comment: You don't normally get the scaling option on monitors not considered 'Retina' or HiDPI, you just get that version in your question. Googling that monitor tells me it's capable of 2560x1440, which is standard for a 27" **2k** monitor, not **HD** [2k on 27" is not considered a retina resolution though]. I can't comment on why it's not showing options up to 2k. I'd at least try shutdown, detach & re-connect the plugs, try again. Has anything else changed since you last saw it correctly?

Comment: @Tetsujin aha, thanks! The monitor info button says 1920 x 1080 when I press it, but 2560 x 1440 sounds about right in terms of scale. I have tried to shutdown and re-attach the cable, but that didn't change anything. The only thing I can think of is the upgrade to macOS Ventura, but that happened a while ago and after upgrading the screen worked correctly for several days.

Comment: @Flobin I have a very similar experience. Upgraded to Ventura 13.1 weeks ago, and just today it all of the sudden stopped playing nicely with my monitor which is 3840x1600. It used to offer the "scaled" options for the display which was working great, but all of the sudden now everything looks tiny and the scaled option is gone.

Comment: @Reilstein I was able to solve the problem with BetterDisplay, see the answer that I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a kind of solution, it doesn’t solve the underlying issue, but I now have a good display resolution. With [BetterDisplay](https://github.com/waydabber/BetterDisplay) I can set the resolution to what I want.

Comment: If anyone like using command line tools then I made a tool that allows to set other resolutions not available in system settings (including scaled HiDPI resolutions) in a similar way as BetterDisplay allows to do it. You can find it here https://github.com/leszek-s/AllResTool

Answer (score 3):

I'm on macOS 14.1 Sonoma facing the same issue.

I got an LG 4K HRD monitor and found when I set it to 4K, the UI is very small. The scaling option is missing, but HDR is OK.

After tweaking around I found its macOS is misleading you.

I found even though I use 1080p, the actual HDMI signal is at 4K.
My display shows 3840x2160, but macOS shows 1080p.

Which means it's already scaled.

macOS secretly outputs 4K but scales it like 1080p and tells you it's 1080p

[image: Photo of the Display settings showing a resolution of 1920x1080 and in the monitor's menu showing a resolution of 3840x2160]